# How to import classPath in new Bumblebee Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

After updating new Bumblebee Android Studio, I created a new project and see that the build.gradle changed with new form

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How could I import new classPath as before? Such as

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$ktl_gradle_ver"
}
```

I wanna to import `classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")`

Comment: did u get an answer?

Comment: I found. But the common solution is Nitin Prakash's below answer

Answer (score 20):

Use buildscript before plugins it will work and put your classpath there in the dependencies block

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5")
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0-rc01' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0-rc01' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: glad, it helps you man...

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found solution, and I comment here for someone need it

```
 id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.4.0' apply(false)
```

Comment: will your solution work ?  here is my classpath, com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin

Comment: what about other classes like firebase crashlytics??

Comment: when i put this i found this issue 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/extension/AndroidComponentsExtension

Comment: Should i put it into gradle.build ?

Comment: @pavel you should look the answer of Nitin Prakash above. my solution must find the source of implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Step 1:**
Open

```
 build.gradle(Project: MyFirstProject)
```

**Step 2:** Add `buildscript` above plugins then add dependencies block inside `buildscript`.

**Reference Code:**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28.3-alpha"
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```